# Mongodb aggregate (problem with $and - $expr)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a problem with mongodb

```
const getBookingStatus = (status) => {
  if (!status) return {};
  const qStatus = {};
  if (status === 'progress') qStatus.$and = [{ $ne: statusList.declined }, { $lt: statusList.confirmed }];
  if (status === 'confirmed') qStatus.$and = [{ $gt: statusList.signed }, { $lt: statusList.completed }];
  if (status === 'done') qStatus.$gte = statusList.completed;
  return { status: { ...qStatus } };
};
```

When I call `const query = ...getBookingStatus(status)`, and use it in a `$match` it works for the `status === 'done'` but doesn't for the others. I have this error : `"message": "unknown operator: $and"`.
I've tried to add `$expr` like :
`if (status === 'progress') qStatus.$expr = { $and: [{ $ne: statusList.declined }, { $lt: statusList.confirmed }] };`
but it doesn't work neither.
Please help me

Comment: How does the result look like (try with `print(tojson(getBookingStatus(...)))` and how do you use it in the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: when i console log = `{ status: { '$and': [ [Object], [Object] ] } }`.
`const res = await Bookings.collection.aggregate([{ $match: query } , (more aggregation things)])`

Comment: Are you sure? `tojson()` should print it as text. Maybe try `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with how the top level `status` field factors into the the comparisons that get nested inside of the `$and`. When using `$and`, each entry is an expression that must reference a field. So right now what gets generated is something like:

```
{
  status:  {
    $and: [
      { $ne: <Val1> }, 
      { $lt: <Val2> }
    ] 
  }
}
```

If you remove the `$and` and the array wrappers, and just provide the two filters as a single object, you will generate something like this instead:

```
{
  status:  {
    $ne: <Val1>, 
    $lt: <Val2>
  }
}
```

This more closely matches what your `'done'` situation generates and successfully uses:

```
{
  status:  {
    $gte: <Val1>
  }
}
```

Here is a basic [playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0pVszsxDRJo).

So the solution is probably to change

```
  if (status === 'progress') qStatus.$and = [{ $ne: statusList.declined }, { $lt: statusList.confirmed }];
  if (status === 'confirmed') qStatus.$and = [{ $gt: statusList.signed }, { $lt: statusList.completed }];
```

To something like:

```
  if (status === 'progress') qStatus = { $ne: statusList.declined, $lt: statusList.confirmed };
  if (status === 'confirmed') qStatus = { $gt: statusList.signed, $lt: statusList.completed };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now with your solution !

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it! Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it was useful